# How to read and Send CR/LF "x0D x0A" in binary mode

Tags: c++, winsock

I am reading a PDF File by opening it in a binary format binary format. I have to send each and every byte to the server via sockets. I am using winsock for this purpose. Following is the code where I am having problem:

```
int Div = (int)file_size / 1024;
int Mod = (int)file_size % 1024;
for (int i=0; i<Div; i++)
{
    file_block = new char[1024];
    myfile.seekg(i*1024);
    myfile.get(file_block,1024);
    send(theSocket,file_block,1024,0);
}
if (Mod != 0)
{
    file_block = new char[Mod];
    myfile.seekg(Div*1024);
    myfile.get(file_block,Mod);
    send(theSocket,file_block,Mod,0);
}
```

When I read the PDF File, my program is stuck after reading first 4 bytes, i.e. `%PDF-1.5`. Seeing the file in Hex Editor reveals that there are `x0D x0A` which is the hex representation of `Carriage Return & Line Feed`.

Is this the reason due to which my program is stuck. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You have a big memory leak, in that you allocate memory in each loop but never free it.

Comment: Make sure you open the file in binary mode at **both** ends of the connection

Comment: The important code is missing, it isn't clear how you opened the file.  Be sure to use ios::binary so it isn't treated like a text file.

Comment: For higher performance, consider using the [`TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which avoids copying the file data from kernel space into user space and back into kernel space again.  Of course, *correctness trumps performance*, so make sure you get your program working before you worry about optimizing.

Comment: @ Captain & Hans: I have used `ios::binary` at both ends !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) you will see that `get` does:

> 3) same as `get(s, count, widen('\n'))`, that is, reads at most count-1 characters and stores them into character string pointed to by s until '\n' is found.

So to start with it will only read until newline. And it will only read `count - 1` characters, in your case 1023 and not 1024 as you expect.

You should be using [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead:

```
myfile.read(file_block, 1024);
```

---

You should probably check for errors as well, and only send if there are none:

```
if (myfile.read(file_block, 1024))
    send(theSocket, file_block, myfile.gcount(), 0);
else
{
    // Error, handle it somehow
}
```

Comment: Also, `send()` may send only a part of the buffer, so an additional loop is needed.